# Can a body rotate indefinitely about its axis in space?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

Wondering if a rigid body can keep rotating about its axis with constant angular velocity without the application of any force or torque, to the object. Assuming that the object is not in influence of any external force (i.e. gravity etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wondering if a rigid body can keep rotating about its axis ...

Yes. If there are no external forces acting on an object then conservation of angular momentum tells us that if it is rotating then it will continue to rotate (at least, as long as we ignore the effect of gravitational waves, which will be negligible unless the object is *very* massive).

> ...with constant angular velocity ...

Not necessarily. Its angular *momentum* will remain constant, but it can change its angular velocity by using internal forces to reconfigure itself and so change its [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia). The canonical example of this is an ice skater pulling in their arms and legs to make themselves spin faster.

Comment: What about the emission of gravitational waves (at least for non-symmetric bodies)?

Comment: @MartinC. Fair point. Caveat added.

Comment: My favorite example of a body's angular velocity changing due to internal forces is [Explorer 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorer_1) (see the first paragraph of the "Results" section.)

Comment: The emission of gravitational forces is a really negligible process for any real rigid body. Probably it could compete with surface sublimation for the most *purely theoretical perturbation* contest. Much more important would be the observation that for a typical non-symmetric body, angular momentum conservation does not imply a rotation around a fixed axis. Missing such a discussion, the answer is severely incomplete.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I agree that, to provide a decent explanation of the rotation of rigid bodies, one would need to discuss torque free precession before discussing the object rearranging itself (the object was previously declared to be rigid so this won't happen). I also agree that it's very unlikely that one could ever construct a human-scale object where gravitational waves were the dominant source of angular deceleration. But the question is just asking if angular momentum dissipates naturally, and the answer suffices for that purpose.